# Is there a fast way in resharper to switch between VS/IntelliJ keyboard shorts layout

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper

I would like to know if there is a keyboard shortcut in resharper to switch between visual studio keyboard layout and intellij keyboard layout

Comment: None to my knowledge. Are you pair programming?

Answer (score 0):

In Resharper options, under visual studio integration, you can set which keyboard layout you like and apply it by pressing "Apply Scheme"

Comment: That's true but there's no shortcut for switching between the two layouts, which is what I guess the question is about

Comment: It takes several seconds to a couple of minutes to go through and re-assign all the keyboard shortcuts; I wouldn't want a shortcut for that...